# Searching for a list of strings from one file to a string in another file

Tags: regex, perl

I have a `file1` with a list of patterns of characters in one column, like this:

```
abcde
defgh
uvwxy
...
```

and `file2` which is just one big string, like this:

```
abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
```

I want to find the location of the match between the strings from `file1` and the single string from `file 2`.

For this I used the index function:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my $string = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
my $char   = "uvwxy" ;

my $result = index($string, $char);

print "Result: $result\n";
```

That works, it matches and gives me the position.

The problem is that I have to enter *manually* every character pattern that I want to match.

How can I tell the software to get the list of character patterns in `/.../file1.txt`?

Comment: Please describe the output that you would like?

Comment: how many and how long are your search strings?  how big is the file you are searching?  do you really just want the first location each search string is found?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read the file into an array then loop.

Have a try with:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

open my $fh, '<', 'path/to/file' or die "unable to open file: $!";
chomp( my @search = <$fh> );

my $string = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";

foreach my $char (@search) {
    my $pos = index( $string, $char );
    if ( $pos != -1 ) {
        print "found $char at position $pos\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: Acutally now it doesn't say anything (because before it would always tell me " position: -1"

Comment: @M42 You might want to `chomp @search;` to get rid of the line endings that are probably stopping matching from occurring.

Comment: @ialarmedalien: true, fixed.

Comment: @chris202 Welcome to SO.  Please give this solution the check mark if it answers your question.